# MAUI (MVVM): Calling a Command in View Model on a Picker Selection Changed

Tags: xaml, mvvm, maui

In .NET MAUI, there is a control "Picker" which doesn't seem to have an option for calling a command within the page View Model. Buttons have a "Command" which allows you to select a command on click of a button. Yet Picker does not seem to have this.

Picker DOES have "SelectedIndexChanged" which allows you to create an event handler in the code behind (xaml.cs file). But this is no good really when I've already adopted a MVVM structure with my app. I want to be able to call a ViewModel command so that I can alter some data in there and change the view display based on the users picker selection.

I think there is probably a way of sending the event handler to the viewmodels command method from the code behind file but this is surely a bit of a rubbish solution...

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to call a command in a viewmodel from the view xaml (if so how?)?
2. If no to the above, what are the best alternatives?
3. Am I interpreting pickers/MVVM/EventHandling wrong? I am open to criticism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to call a command in a viewmodel from the view xaml ?

As Jason said, [EventToCommandBehavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/behaviors/event-to-command-behavior) could do that. Here is how to [Get Started with the .NET Multi-platform App UI (.NET MAUI) Community Toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/get-started?tabs=CommunityToolkitMaui).

Suppose we define a Picker in xaml.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
  ....       
         xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit">

    <Picker x:Name="picker" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
        Title="Select a monkey">
        <Picker.Behaviors>
            <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="SelectedIndexChanged"
             Command="{Binding SelectedIndexChangeCommand}" />
        </Picker.Behaviors>
    </Picker>
```

And in viewModel, we use the command

```
    public Command SelectedIndexChangeCommand
    {

        get
        {
            return new Command(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("123");
            });
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps!

---

**Update**

If you don't want to use `EventToCommandBehavior`, you could also get access to ViewModel and modify the property in code behind.

Below is the SelectedIndexChanged event handler,

```
void picker_SelectedIndexChanged(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    var picker = sender as Picker;
    var viewModel = this.BindingContext as MainPageViewModel;
    viewModel.Title = (string)picker.SelectedItem;
}
```

Comment: `<Picker ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding Title}" Title="Select a monkey">` is too simple?

Comment: I just answer op's question :)

Comment: +1. This worked for me first try. I'm sure the other solutions people provided work as well so thank you all for your help. Much appreciated!

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT "If no to the above, what are the best alternatives?"

Answer (score 0):

The `Picker` class has a bindable property named [`SelectedItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.picker.selecteditem?view=net-maui-8.0#microsoft-maui-controls-picker-selecteditem) or [`SelectedIndex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.picker.selectedindex?view=net-maui-8.0) and both will change the bound property in the ViewModel when the Picker selection has changed.

You can subscribe to the `PropertyChanged` event in the ViewModel itself if you need to react to that change.